# Java Junit Test with Hamcrest: cannot create compositional Matcher

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I am new to unit testing in Java and am having a bit of trouble replicating something I performed in a tutorial.

I have an email class which has many properties, but among them is `firstName`.

```
private final String firstName;
public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
}
```

The first name is set in the constructor in a standard fashion:

```
this.firstName = firstName;
```

I've written a test to test if the email contains a first name. After set up the test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void emailIsCreated() {
    assertThat(em1, hasProperty("firstName"));
}
```

This test passes.
My problem is that I'm trying to extend the test with a compositional matcher to match the values of the firstname like so:

```
@Test
public void emailIsCreated() {
    assertThat(em1, hasProperty("firstName", equalTo("Jon")));
}
```

But I keep getting a compile error that reads:

`hasProperty (String) in HasProperty cannot be applied to (String, org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>)`

My intuition tells me it has a problem with equating the strings based on the message (and the fact that when I successfully preformed this before I was matching an int), but that doesn't seem right...
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `hasProperty` from the wrong place. [HasProperty](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasProperty.html) does not have method with signature `(String, org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>)` as error message shows and as you can double check in the java API doc above.

[Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) on the other hand has both `hasProperty` methods imported from [HasProperty](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasProperty.html) and [HasPropertyWithValue](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/HasPropertyWithValue.html).

So the fix is to change the import and use `org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty` instead of `org.hamcrest.beans.HasProperty.hasProperty`